# how to auto show a expand item in list when it in bottom of the screen?

Tags: flutter-listview

I want  to make a  expand item list, and  when the item is expanded   all of this item view can be shown,
I try to do  something in the onExpansionChanged like :

```
_controller.position.animateTo(item.height * expanded item count  +containerPosition.dy,
duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.easeOut);
```

but it does not work.

Can I assign an item by position to scroll?